# DOM Shadow add event

Tags: javascript, shadow-dom, dom-events

I set one eventListener on document.body capturing all events, added some widgets using Shadow Dom and I want to capture those events as well.

e.target for event inside shadow is only available if event is set on the shadowroot itself so forced to create a second event.

This creates a scenario where two events are firing at random order and application fails.

is there some pattern for handling this scenario and emit only shadowroot event if both fire?

script to test

```
<script>

addShadow = function(){
    var d = document.createElement('div')
    var p = document.createElement('p')
    p.textContent = 'target me';
    d.attachShadow({'mode' : 'open'});
    d.shadowRoot.appendChild(p);
    document.body.appendChild(d);
    document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e){
      console.log('body click');
      console.log(e.target);
    })

    d.shadowRoot.addEventListener('click', function(e){
      console.log('shadowClick');
      console.log(e.target);
    })
}

addShadow();

</script>
```

Comment: added  code, hopefully this helps

Comment: what is the problem? events are always caught in the same ordre in the given example